# Better way to do multiple try/except in Python

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
    lengths = []
    lengths.append(len(self.download_links))
    lengths.append(len(self.case_names))
    lengths.append(len(self.case_dates))
    lengths.append(len(self.docket_numbers))
    lengths.append(len(self.neutral_citations))
    lengths.append(len(self.precedential_statuses))
```

Unfortunately, any of those object properties can be `None`, so I need to check each with either an `if not None` block or a `try/except` block. Checking each individually will blow up the size and conciseness of the code.

I assume there must be a better way for this kind of pattern, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, consider whether these shouldn't be `None`, but instead should be empty lists. Most of the time `None` is better replaced by something else like an empty list.

If that's not an option, you can use a list:

```
for item in [self.download_links, self.case_name...]:
    if item is not None:
         length.append( len(item) )
```

or a function

```
def add_length(obj):
   if obj is not None:
            lengths.append(len(obj))

add_length(self.download_links)
add_length(self.case_name)
...
```

Comment: I think `None` is better semantically in this case than [], but this will do it, and makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @mlissner: If something could be `None` or a `list` I'd say it's a bad design choice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just try some list comprehensions:

```
chunks = [self.download_links, self.case_name...]
lengths = [len(i) for i in chunks if i is not None]
```